# Dereferencing this pointer gives me -46, but I am not sure why

Tags: c, pointers, casting, dereference

This is a program I ran:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int y = 1234;
    char *p = &y;
    int *j = &y;
    printf("%d %d\n", *p, *j);
}
```

I am slightly confused about the output. What I'm seeing is:

```
-46 1234
```

I wrote this program as an experiment and wasn't sure what it was going to output. I was expecting possibly one byte from `y`.

What is happening "behind-the-scenes" here? How does dereferencing `p` give me `-46`?

As pointed out by others, I had to do explicit casting to not cause UB. I am not changing that line from `char *p = &y;` to `char *p = (char *)&y;` so that I am not invalidating the answers below.

This program is not causing any UB behaviour as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496014/type-casting-char-pointer-to-integer-pointer?rq=1).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have something like ,

```
int x = 1234;
int *p = &x;
```

If You Dereference Pointer `p` then it will correctly read integer bytes. Because You declared it to be pointer to `int` . It will know how many bytes to read by `sizeof()` operator. Generally size of `int` is `4 bytes` (for 32/64-bit platforms) but it is machine dependent that is why it will use `sizeof()` operator to know correct size and will read so.

For Your Code

```
 int y = 1234;
 char *p = &y;
 int *j  = &y;
```

Now `pointer p` points to `y` but we have declared it to be pointer to a `char` so it will only read one byte or whatever byte char is of .
`1234` in binary would be represented as

`00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010`

Now if your machine is little endian it will store the bytes reversing them

`11010010 00000100 00000000 00000000`

`11010010` is at `address 00` `Hypothetical address`, `00000100` is at `address 01` and so on.

```
BE:      00   01   02   03
       +----+----+----+----+   
    y: | 00 | 00 | 04 | d2 |
       +----+----+----+----+


LE:      00   01   02   03
       +----+----+----+----+
    y: | d2 | 04 | 00 | 00 |
       +----+----+----+----+

(In Hexadecimal)
```

So now if you dereference `pointer p` it will read only first byte and output will be (`-46`in case of `signed char` and `210` in case of `unsigned char`, according to the C standard the signed-ness of plain char is "implementation defined.) as Byte read would be `11010010`(because we pointed `signed char`(in this case it is `signed char`).

On your PC negative numbers are represented as [2's Complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) so the `most-significant bit` is the sign bit. First bit `1` denotes the sign. `11010010 = –128 + 64 + 16 + 2 = –46` and if you dereference `pointer j` it will completely read all bytes of `int` as we declared it to be pointer to `int` and output will be `1234`

If you declare pointer j as `int *j` then `*j` will read `sizeof(int)` here 4 bytes(machine dependent). Same goes with `char` or any other data type the pointer pointed to them will read as many bytes there size is of , `char` is of 1 byte.

As others have pointed, you need to explicitly cast to `char*` as `char *p = &y;` is a constraint violation - `char *` and `int *` are not compatible types, instead write `char *p = (char *)&y`.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` does not necessarily `== 4`.

Comment: Your example is missing a cast to `char *`, as we can only implicitly convert to `void *`. It would be worth mentioning that only `[[un]signed] char *` is allowed to alias other types via pointer/reference, in order to read their object representation as a series of `char`s. We are not allowed, e.g. to declare a `char[4]` (or whatever our `sizeof(int)` is), fill it with values, and try to read it via an `int *`, as that breaks assumptions about aliasing, alignment, and others.

Comment: A pointer of any `char` type - `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char` - can alias any other type. But the converse isn't true: we can't legally take a bunch of `char`s & read them as another type e.g. `int`. Some compilers let you do it; that doesn't mean it's legal. Trying to read an object's memory as-if it contains an incompatible type causes _undefined behaviour_, so the compiler can produce an error, work exactly as you expect, or do anything. More so, where both pointers are in scope, aliasing rules mean the illegal attempt to reinterpret can be optimised away to something you don't want

Comment: @SurajJain This answers is mostly correct. I would correct the following: *Generally char is of 1 byte*: it is always 1 byte. *Generally size of int is 4 bytes*: it is true if 32/64-bit platforms (and not true for 8-bit platforms for example). Also as @JohnBode says in its answers `char *p = &y;` is invalid and a cast is required.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of issues with the code as written.

First of all, you are invoking *undefined behavior* by trying to print the numeric representation of a `char` object using the `%d` conversion specifier:

[Online C 2011 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §7.21.6.1, subclause 9:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) **If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.**

Yes, objects of type `char` are promoted to `int` when passed to variadic functions; `printf` is special, and if you want the output to be well-defined, then the type of the argument and the conversion specifier *must* match up.  To print the numeric value of a `char` with `%d` or `unsigned char` argument with `%u`, `%o`, or `%x`, you must use the `hh` length modifier as part of the conversion spec:

```
printf( "%hhd ", *p );
```

The second issue is that the line

```
char *p = &y;
```

is a constraint violation - `char *` and `int *` are not compatible types, and may have different sizes and/or representations<sup>2</sup>.  Thus, you *must* explicitly cast the source to the target type:

```
char *p = (char *) &y;
```

The *one* exception to this rule occurs when one of the operands is `void *`; then the cast isn't necessary.

Having said all that, I took your code and added a utility that dumps the address and contents of objects in the program.  Here's what `y`, `p`, and `j` look like on my system (SLES-10, gcc 4.1.2):

```
       Item        Address   00   01   02   03
       ----        -------   --   --   --   --
          y 0x7fff1a7e99cc   d2   04   00   00    ....

          p 0x7fff1a7e99c0   cc   99   7e   1a    ..~.
            0x7fff1a7e99c4   ff   7f   00   00    ....

          j 0x7fff1a7e99b8   cc   99   7e   1a    ..~.
            0x7fff1a7e99bc   ff   7f   00   00    ....
```

I'm on an x86 system, which is little-endian, so it stores multi-byte objects starting with the least-significant byte at the lowest address:

```
BE:      A   A+1  A+2  A+3
       +----+----+----+----+
    y: | 00 | 00 | 04 | d2 |
       +----+----+----+----+
LE:     A+3  A+2  A+1   A
```

On a little-endian system, the addressed byte is the least-significant byte, which in this case is `0xd2` (`210` unsigned, `-46` signed).

In a nutshell, you're printing the signed, decimal representation of that single byte.

As for the broader question, the type of the *expression* `*p` is `char` and the type of the *expression* `*j` is `int`; the compiler simply goes by the type of the expression.  The compiler keeps track of all objects, expressions, and types as it translates your source to machine code.  So when it sees the expression `*j`, it knows that it's dealing with an integer value and generates machine code appropriately.  When it sees the expression `*p`, it knows it's dealing with a `char` value.

---

1. Admittedly, almost all modern desktop systems that I know of use the same representations for all pointer types, but for more oddball embedded or special-purpose platforms, that may not be true.

   § 6.2.5, subclause 28.

Comment: @SurajJain: The `*p = &y` line is a *constraint violation* (both operands must be of compatible types), so the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic. As to what will happen if you leave the cast off, that depends on a lot of things.  If you're working on a platform where all pointer types have the same size and representation, then your code will most likely work as intended.  If pointer sizes and representations differ, then you could see anything from garbled data to a runtime error.  (or nothing at all).

Comment: @SurajJain: As for dasblinkenlight's answer...I tend to take an absolutist view when it comes to matching up conversions and arguments in `printf` calls, mainly because I've been bitten by that in the past.  If you're passing a `char` argument, then you *should* use either `%c` or `%hhd` (or `%hho` or `%hhx` or `%hhu` for `unsigned char`).  Yes, because promotions are a thing in variadic functions, you should be able to print a `char` value using `%d`, but I will argue that such code is less than clear.

Comment: This answer currently says: _you are invoking undefined behavior by trying to print the numeric representation of a `char` object using the `%d` conversion specifier_ — which is, to be polite about it, hogwash.  There is absolutely nothing undefined about it.  There is implementation-defined behaviour, but that's not undefined.  It is implementation-defined whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned, which affects the `int` value that the `char` is converted to, but that's all.

Comment: The arguments after the format string to `printf()` undergo the default promotion rules ([C11 §6.5.2.2 Function calls, ¶6-7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6)) because of the ellipsis in the function prototype.

Comment: @John Bode, It looks like you made a mistake in the first part of your question. Could you fix it so it can be accepted?

Comment: @ikegami He did not fixed it.

Comment: Typo in my comment: s/your question/your answer

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(Please note this answer refers to the original form of the question, which asked how the program knew how many bytes to read, etc. I'm keeping it around on that basis, despite the rug having been pulled out from under it.)</sub>

A pointer refers to a location in memory that contains a particular object and must be incremented/decremented/indexed with a particular stride size, reflecting the `sizeof` the pointed type.

The observable value of the pointer itself (e.g. through `std::cout << ptr`) need not reflect any recognisable physical address, nor does `++ptr` need to increment said value by 1, `sizeof(*ptr)`, or anything else. A pointer is just a handle to an object, with an implementation-defined bit representation. That representation doesn't and shouldn't matter to users. The only thing for which users should use the pointer is to... well, point to stuff. Talk of its address is nonportable and only useful in debugging.

Anyway, simply, the compiler knows how many bytes to read/write because the pointer is typed, and that type has a defined `sizeof`, representation, and mapping to physical addresses. So, based on that type, operations on `ptr` will be compiled to appropriate instructions in order to calculate the real hardware address (which again, need not correspond to the observable value of `ptr`), read the right `sizeof` number of memory 'bytes', add/subtract the right number of bytes so it points at the next object, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First read the warning which says 
**warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     char *p = &y;**

which means you should do **explicit typecasting** to avoid undefined behaviour according to **standard §7.21.6.1, subclause 9** (pointed by @john Bode) as

```
chat *p = (char*)&y;
```

and

```
int y =1234;
```

here `y` is the `local variable` and it will be stores in the `stack` section of `RAM`.In Linux machine integers are stored in memory according to `little endian` format. Assume `4 bytes` of memory reserved for `y` is from `0x100` to `0x104`

```
    -------------------------------------------------
    | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0100 | 1101 0010 |
    -------------------------------------------------
    0x104      0x103       0x102       0x101       0x100
                                                    y
                                                    p
                                                    j
```

As pointed above, `j` and `p` both points to same address `0x100` but when compiler will perform `*p` since `p` is `signed character pointer` by default it will check `sign bit` and here `sign bit` is `1` means one thing is sure that output it's going to print is **negative number**.

If `sign bit` is `1` i.e negative number and **Negative numbers are stored in Memory as 2's compliment** So

```
    actual          => 1101 0010 (1st byte)
    ones compliment => 0010 1101
                              +1
                      ------------
                       0010  1110 => 46 and since sign bit was one it will print -46
```

while printing if you are using `%u` format specifier which is for printing `unsigned` equivalent, it will `not` check `sign bi`t, finally whatever data is there in `1 byte` gets printed.

finally

```
printf("%d\n",*j);
```

In above statement while doing dereferencing `j` which is `signed pointer` by default and its a `int` pointer so it will check **31st bit** for **sign**, which is `0` means output will be `positive` no and that is 1234.